# Images only show on browser resize/reflow

Tags: reactjs, image, react-apollo, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to the describe the following as good as possible. I am happy if you ask more questions to get me closer to a solution or even what the problem is.

My setup with a React-app, SSR with Razzle, graphQL with Apollo. Also tried the same with Nextjs.

After navigating from **/shop** to **/shop/shopdetail** the images are first visible after browser resize or navigating back to **/shop** and into **/shop/shopdetail** again. The image URL are provided by a GraphQL query inside **/shopdetail**.

[image: Before resize] [image: After resize]

Before and after resize.

But the images seem to get loaded from the dev-server.

[image: Chrome dev tools]

Some of the images when first rendered, only when direkt after SSR have a MIME-type text/plain, is this normal?

**What I have tried:**

- using  tag with and without src-set
- same setup with Razzle and Next
- set min-height in px on parent container and on img
- Different browsers: Shopdetail images are shown Firefox but not in Chrome and Safari

ADDED CODE (image component that processes and gets all the images):

```
const ImageSrcset = ({ sizes, id, imageFormats, fit, position, data }) => {
  let srcSet = '';
  let srcSetJson = '';
  let singleImg;
  let jsonEmpty = true;

  const {
    mediathek: { backgroundColor, source, data: json }
  } = data;
  const { url: srcBeforeSlice } = source;
  const src = srcBeforeSlice.slice(9);

  // Image processing if JSON with image data from graphQL is empty
  src &&
    sizes.forEach(size => {
      const path = `/api/images/${src}?width=${size}&sizes=[${sizes}]&id=${id}&imageFormats=${imageFormats} ${size}w, `;
      srcSet = srcSet + path;
    });

  // Setting src-set from JSON graphQL data
  if (((json && Object.keys(json)) || {}).length >= 1) {
    jsonEmpty = false;
    json &&
      json.jpg.forEach((image, index) => {
        const line = `/images/${json.dir}/${image.url} ${image.w}w,`;
        index === 0 && (singleImg = `/images/${json.dir}/${image.url}`);
        srcSetJson = srcSetJson + line;
      });
  }

  const fitImage =
    fit === 'contain'
      ? {
          objectFit: 'contain',
          width: '100%',
          height: 'auto'
        }
      : fit;

  return (
    <Main backgroundColor={backgroundColor} fit={fitImage} position={position}>
      {src && jsonEmpty ? (
        // route for image-processing and pipe image back
        <img src={singleImg} srcSet={srcSet} sizes="100vw" alt={src} />
      ) : (
        // route when image URL received from GraphQL
        <img src={singleImg} srcSet={srcSetJson} sizes="100vw" alt={src} /> || null
      )}
    </Main>
  );
};

ImageSrcset.defaultProps = {
  sizes: [320, 640, 768, 1024, 1150, 1366, 1500, 1600, 1750, 1920],
  imageFormats: ['jpg', 'webp'],
  fit: {
    objectFit: 'cover',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  },
  zIndex: 'auto',
  json: {},
  src: null,
  position: 'absolute'
};

const IMAGE_QUERY = gql`
  query image($id: ID!) {
    mediathek(id: $id) {
      _id
      source {
        url
      }
      backgroundColor
      data
      order
    }
  }
`;

export default graphql(IMAGE_QUERY, {
  options: props => ({ variables: { id: props.id } }),
  props: ({ data }) => ({
    data
  })
})(ImageSrcset);
```

Comment: Can you provide some code, for example when you call your GraphQL query to retrieve those image URL and where you render them inside your page ?

Comment: Yes. I have added some code from my image component. Do you want more code?